# how to load and save form field data for checkbox from other entity in symfony2

Tags: forms, symfony, symfony-2.4, fieldtype

Project: Symfony 2.4, FOSUserBundle, SonataUserBundle.

## Task

I have `User` entity and profile form for it. I want to add checkbox for reminder subscription. This is saved in different entity 'Setting' (with one way relation Setting -> User). If there is row in 'Setting' for user checkbox should be checked, if row does not exist - it should be unchecked. So I need:

1. render checkbox
2. load data
3. save data

## Implementation

### 1. Render check box

I know it depends on field type (because I think I could use `entity` type) but now I have this code:

```
class ProfileFormType extends ProfileType
{
    $builder
    ->add("subscribeReminder", "checkbox",
        array(
            "mapped" => false,
            'required'  => false,
        )
    );
}
```

### 2. Load data

I *think* it could be done using 'class' and 'query_builder' in field options but I was not successful in doing that. Need to set checkbox to true when setting exists.

### 3. Save data

I *think* I could save data in FormHandler->onSuccess() (passing repository to constructor). Need to delete row or to create one.

## Down the road

I am completely lost in documentation. It is possible to implement EventListeners, EventSubscribers. Tried different approaches with no luck. I think (hope) there is something simpler.

Answer (score 0):

If you can make a property or method in User class which will return true if User is subscribed, you can add something like this at the end of your buildForm() method:

```
$user = $builder->getData();
if($user instanceof User && $user->isSubscribed())
{
    $builder->remove('subscribeReminder');
}
```

If you cannot make such a method or property, use the options array. Get a boolean value in controller for example if your user is subscribed, and pass the value as an option to your form, like so:

```
$form = $formFactory->create($formType, $entity, array('isSubscribed' => true));
```

I have passed true for simplicity, but you should pass the right boolean.

Then in your form type, add this method:

```
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'isSubscribed' => false
    ));
}
```

For extra security, you can also validate the passed option with $resolver->setAllowedTypes() ...

And in your buildForm() add this at the end:

```
if($options['isSubscribed'])
{
    $builder->remove('subscribeReminder');
}
```

Sorry for any typos, and good luck!:)

And the last part of your question, you can add form events, but I think it is better to keep things simple is this scenario.

You can add event listeners to form like this inside buildForm():

```
$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::SUBMIT, function(FormEvent $event) use ($something)
{
    ...
}
```